# Change Window on Button Click

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

In my current solution I have 2 projects:

1) A ClassLibrary project containing models and view models and

2) a project called UI containing 2 windows, a LoginWindow and a MainWindow.

Currently, the UI project has a reference to the ClassLibrary project to get the view models. The problem arises when I want to change the window from the LoginWindow to the MainWindow. I have read some articles and searches the internet for a few days now, but nothing seems to give a satisfying result in terms of what I am actually looking for. Typically it concerns a single window maintaining/switching between multiple views. That's not what I want. I want the LoginWindow to change to the MainWindow and close the LoginWindow on a button click. How is this achievable?

Edit1: I guess I need to clarify that I am using MVVM and need to access appropiate view models. I can’t just make a new instance of a certain window whenever needed and show it while hiding the other.

Edit2:

```
public static class MainTest
{
    public static int Test()
    {
        Thread app = new Thread((ThreadStart)delegate
        {
            LoginWindow login = new LoginWindow();
            LoginViewModel loginVM = new LoginViewModel();

            if (loginVM.IsLoggedIn == false)
            {
                return -1;
            }
            else
            {
                MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
                mainWindow.Show();
            }
        }

        app.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        app.Start();
        return 0;
    }

}
```

[SOLVED] At `return -1` I get an error saying: "**Anonymous function converted to a void returning delegate cannot return a value**"

At `app.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);`I get an error saying: **Argument2: cannot convert from 'void' to 'int'.** I assume this has something to do with the delegate, you've written at the very top of the code.

Edit3:

[image]

Comment: which solution you already tried didn't satisfy your requirement and how did each one fail?

Comment: Won't create instance of `MainWindow`, calling `mainWindow.Show()` (assuming `mainWindow` is you `MainWindow` object) and `this.Close()` help?

Comment: I have tried what these articles suggest, but they apply to switching between multiple views within a window, which is not what I seek to accomplish https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/navigation-with-mvvm-2/ and http://www.technical-recipes.com/2016/switching-between-wpf-xaml-views-using-mvvm-datatriggers/

Comment: @Kentah I did a simple mistake. Just remove -1 inside the if

Comment: That removed the error, but the `app.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);` still gives me an error. There also seems to be a problem with the `Thread app = new Thread((ThreadStart)delegate` in terms of an opening bracket? I will post a screenshot. I guess it's how the code is written inside the delegate?

Answer (score 0):

I usually use a main class to do this.

- Create a main class that has this method inside

  ```
  public static int Main()
  {
      Thread app = new Thread((ThreadStart)delegate
      {
          MyLoginControl login = new MyLoginControl();
          MyLoginVM lvm = new MyLoginVM();
          login.DataConetxt = lvm;
          login.ShowDialog();
          if (lvm.IsLoginFailed)
          {
              return;
          }
          else
          {
             MainWindow myApp = new MainWindow();
             MyAppVm avm = new MyAppVm();
             myApp.DataContext = avm;
             myApp.ShowDialog();
          }
      }
      app.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
      app.Start();
      return 0;
  }
  ```
- In your project Properties (in visual studio right click on your project --> Properties) in the application tab set your Main class as startup object

This will allow you to run the login and check also the result before starting the actual application, without shutting down when the login view return

**EDIT**: Added an example of how you can use your VM. The point is that you can do what you want in this method. It's only purpose is to prevent the application to shutdown when the login view return (normally a Dispose() would be launched internally causing the shutdown of the application on window return)

**EDIT2**: there was a little error in my code. Fixed

Comment: I don’t see how this would do me any good as I won’t be able to use the code that resides in my LoginViewModel. I somehow need to change window after my command has finished executing and done necessary checks making sure the username and password are correct.

Comment: I don't see where is your problem at all honestly. This approach is not in contrast with mvvm patter. I have a vm for my login too. Ofc this code is an example and you need to modify it based on your need

Comment: My solution is split up in 2 projects meaning that the views have access to view models, however, view models do not have access to views directly (you can't make an instance of a window in the view model classes). Therefore, the way you have shown won't apply to my solution. I hope that I am making sense. My guess is that you want me to make your suggested class in my ClassLibrary project, which results in me not being able to make an instance of a window and show it.

Comment: Again... i can't understand which is your problem. Add the main in your application project. Call the login, do the stuff you need to do and run main window on succesfull login. Of course you need to reference it. I prefer that my login is a dll but it doesn't make any difference. If you are looking for something different be more specific. Cause i don't like it isn't a real problem to me

Comment: @Kentah modified the example to show that you can call your viewmodel. If you assigned the datacontext using xaml the code isn't very different. You just need to cast inside the main the datacontext of your view

Comment: Hey! Thank you for trying to help out. I tried implementing your, however, I get a few errors. Are you sure that the code you posted is in working condition? I will post what I have done in a second.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, 
In your app.config file define the StartupUri xaml as login.xaml :

```
         Application x:Class="CapronCRM.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         StartupUri="Login.xaml">
```

And in your login xaml, when the login attemt is successfull, call this code :

```
            MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();
            mw.Show();
            this.Close();
```

Comment: This won’t work as I am using MVVM and need to access the code which resides in my LoginViewModel.